# 2004 Pacifica overheats

Tags: engine, oil, coolant, block

1. Heater core had completely busted
2. Coolant leaked into car floor on driver's side
3. Had the heater core fixed
4. Car wasn't flushed out
5. Engine oil empty
6. Engine oil mixed into the coolant
7. Caused a blockage.

**Question:**

1. Where is the blockage located?
2. Should we flush it out and renew the engine oil, coolant, and antifreeze?
3. Does it need a new engine after flushing it out or am I ok?

Comment: How many miles on the car?  Does the engine leak oil onto the ground?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for us to know where the blockage is. What I can tell is there seems to be a number of things wrong with this car that may not necessarily be related to each other.

**Engine oil in the coolant is a bad thing.** It is usually an indication of blown head gasket, cracked head or block. A broken heater core will not cause it. Yes, it needs to be flushed out, but not until you find where the oil leak is.

There is no way we can tell you if your engine is OK or not with the little information you have given. You best thing for you to do is have it towed to a mechanic to find out what is happening (I say towed because driving it in this condition could actually ruin the engine if it isn't already).